# putting an ExtJS component inside of a div

Tags: javascript, extjs

i m trying to put an ExtJS form into a div. But when i do that all the view is getting messed up. Any idea how can i fit ExtJS components inside of divs ?

```
 var configurationsContent=$('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">'+"Page 3" +'</div>').appendTo(tabContent);
 var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Support Ticket Request',
    width: 650,
    height: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: 'margin: 50px',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'First Name', 
            name: 'FirstName',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            cls: 'field-margin',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',  
            name: 'LastName',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            cls: 'field-margin',
            flex: 1
        }]
    }]
});
        formPanel.appendTo(configurationsContent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
```

with

```
renderTo: 'theIdOfYourDiv'
```

and remove

```
formPanel.appendTo(configurationsContent);
```

(because there is no `appendTo` method on `Ext.form.Panel`).

Comment: still i cant see the textfields on the page ?

Comment: I am sorry for not having telepathic powers, so please post a fiddle.